# Encoding Image into Base64 using Kotlin for Android Application

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

`(Not duplicate / I did research)`

- Using `Kotlin` for `Android`
- `min API level` is `19`

I am trying to `encode` the `image` file into `Base64`

My image path looks like this:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.android/files/Pictures/1234.jpg
```

I saved the path into a variable called `photo_path`

Now I do this to convert the image into `Base64`

```
val bytes = File(photo_path).readBytes()
var imgBase64 = android.util.Base64.encode(bytes, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);

println("imgBase64: " + imgBase64)
```

When I print the output the value of `imgBase64`, I get this:

```
imgBase64: [B@4202e71
```

Could anyone please help me understand what the output is and how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [`encodeToString`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64#encodeToString(byte%5B%5D,%20int)) method if you want output as `String`

```
val imgBase64 = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(bytes, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT)
```

Comment: are you sure that your app has access to this file?

Comment: I am on an emulator, I think it has access.

Comment: It's not a fact at all :) Is this image the part of your app?

Comment: Yes, I take the image from the app and I get the path. After that, I use the path to convert into Base64

Comment: it will be easier to put it into the `raw` resources folder of the project like `yourApp/app/src/main/res/raw/test.jpg`. And then get image's bytes like `val bytes = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.test).readBytes()`

Comment: It works when I put the path but it does not work when I take the picture. What could have happened? Both outputs is the same.

Comment: sorry, I don't get your problem

Comment: So when I use the URL text it works, but when I pass it as a parameter it is not working.